# Elastic Stack architecture recommandations in production

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

we have an ELK cluster with 3 ES data, 2 ES master. We have also 2 Logstash and 1 kibana.
Is it recommended to have a load balancer between logstash and ES nodes?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a big ES cluster, just 3 data nodes, and all the data nodes by default takes [coordinating role](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#coordinating-node) apart from this, from ES 6.1 [Adaptive replica selection](https://www.elastic.co/blog/improving-response-latency-in-elasticsearch-with-adaptive-replica-selection) is included which is by default on from ES 7.X.

So in your case, IMHO there is no need to add load-balancer between logstash and ES nodes.

Comment: so if i understand we only need something like this?
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["ES data node1:port1", "ES data node2:port2", "ES data node3: port"]
    }
}

Comment: @AbdallahMoujahid, above is the output of what?? you don't have to do anything extra, if all the data nodes are already part of same cluster :)

Comment: i was talking about the configuration of logstash. what i mentioned was the modification to make in the output plugin? is that correct?

Comment: @AbdallahMoujahid no need to mention all the three nodes, as all these three nodes are part of same cluster, you can just mention the host and ip of any node in the cluster

Comment: Thanks a lot! what happen if the referenced node is down or unavailable?

Comment: @AbdallahMoujahid, yeah if you have this issue, better to give all the node in the configuration :)